# How hide multiple lines using Livecode

Tags: livecode

I am try to hide text between begin{equation} and end{equation}. I am using the following code and it's working. But my problem is it's only work once if more than one begin{equation} and end{equation} is there then it's not working.

```
on mouseUp
       put wordOffset("begin{equation}",fld "MyField") into tBegin
       put wordOffset("end{equation}",fld "MyField") into tEnd
          set the hidden of line tBegin to tEnd of fld "MytextField" to true
    end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the 'wordsToSkip' parameter of wordOffset in the LC dictionary. If you don't manage this and have several sets of equation text to find then your code will always find, and stop at, the first match it finds.

You have two ways you could handle multiple instances of equation text - either edit the text to be searched as you proceed or make use of the 'wordsToSkip' parameter.

First use a repeat loop with an 'if' statement to find out how many instances of your 'begin{equation} flag are contained in the text to search. Then set up another repeat loop and use approach a) or b)...

Approach a) don't use 'wordsToSkip', copy the text to be searched into a temporary variable and simply remove all the text up to any previously found instances of your flag.

Approach b) keep the text to be searched whole and place the char number + 1 of the endpoint of previously found instances in the 'wordsToSkip' parameter.

Comment: can you give a example please.